# Em Rust como funciona ampersand e asterisco?

Tags: operadores, cast, referência, rust

Vim do Java recentemente e estou estudando Rust. A linguagem tem paradigma totalmente diferente do qual estava acostumado, mas me chamou muito a atenção. Por nunca ter mexido com C ou C++, às vezes encontro dificuldades aparentemente bobas.

Fiquei na dúvida sobre os operadores `&` (*ampersand* ou *e-comercial*) e `*` (asterisco). Quando devo os utilizar e como funcionam?

Pelo que percebi, o operador `&` cria uma, digamos, referência; e o `*` converte uma referencia para um tipo não referenciado, mas não tenho certeza se é isso mesmo.

```
let x = 10;
let y =  &x;
println!("{}", *y == x); // true
```

O código acima funciona perfeitamente, apesar de não entender o que ele faz, eu sei que `y` acaba se tornando do tipo `&i32` cujo seja uma referencia do `x` que é do tipo `i32`, logo imaginei que convertendo com alias funcionaria também.

```
let x = 10;
let y =  x as &i32; // Error: non-primitive cast: `i32` as `&i32`
println!("{}", *y == x);
```

Porém acontece um erro quando tento converter. Então eu tentei:

```
let x = 10;
let y =  &x;
println!("{}", y as i32 == x); // Error: cannot cast `&i32` as `i32`; casting `&i32` as `i32` is invalid
```

Nesse ultimo caso o compilador detecta o erro e o *helper* me sugere usar `y` no lugar de `y as i32`.

Então queria entender porque ele me sugere isso. Se possível me explicar o funcionamento do `*` e `&`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basicamente você entendeu. O `&` cria uma referência, então o valor que obterá é um ponteiro, ou seja, um endereço de memória do local onde realmente está o dado (referência é algo que se refere a algo). Entenda a referência como um endereço onde está uma casa, e a casa é o objeto real.

Quando você declara `x` com valor 10. implicitamente está dizendo que o tipo dessa variável é um `int32` (há uma inferência do tipo de acordo com o valor colocado), então é reservado um espaço na memória para colocar um valor deste tipo (é reservado 4 bytes).

Quando você declara `y` está implicitamente dizendo que o valor é um endereço para alguma coisa (o tal operador `&` indica isto), então tem que reservar um espaço na memória para guardar isto (os tamanhos mais típicos são 4 ou 8 bytes dependendo da arquitetura ser 32 ou 64 bits).

Entenda que o valor de `y` é o endereço de onde está `x`, conforme indica a expressão usada. Cada variável terá um valor diferente, um é 10 e o outro é algo parecido com #F2C8D4 (notação hexadecimal tipicamente usada em endereços) que é o endereço de memória onde está o 10.

Note que os dois tipos são muito diferentes. Mesmo quando ele tem 4 bytes é só uma coincidência, toda semântica do tipo é diferente. Em hipótese alguma você pode confundir uma coisa com a outra, é como comparar abacate com picanha. ambos são de comer mas em contextos diferentes e jeitos de preparar muito distintos, você não pode usar do mesmo jeito.

Se você tentar acessar `y` em tese você deveria acessar o endereço contido ali. Mas quase nunca é o que deseja, então a linguagem provê o acesso indireto automático ao valor referenciado por este endereço. Isto quer dizer que se o objeto estiver em contexto isolado você não precisa usar o `*`. Mas pode usar se acha melhor deixar explícito. Em alguns casos se não fizer isto dará problema. O caso usado na pergunta é um deles.

Se você tentar comparar `y` que é um endereço com `x` que é um inteiro, os tipos são incompatíveis e não tem como dar um resultado adequado, então precisa fazer algo para torná-los compatíveis e aí depende do que deseja. Pode querer comparar endereços e aí o inteiro virar um endereço, ou pode querer comparar o valor do inteiro com o valor apontado do outro lado. Você tem que ser explícito no que quer. Então usando o `*` está dizendo que quer pegar o valor apontado por `y` para comparar com o valor contido em `x`.

Como o valor apontado por `y` é exatamente o mesmo objeto de `x` não tem nem como ser diferente.

Olhando de outra forma, vamos transformar os operadores em funções para dar o resultado que deseja. Primeiro vamos fazer a adição que é um operador que todos entendem:

```
y + x
y.plus(x)
y = &x
y = AddressOf(x)
*y = x
ValueOfAddress(y) == x
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Rust/Addressof.rs).

O `as` não funciona porque não tem nenhuma regra específica criada para fazer os tipos se tornarem compatíveis fazendo isto, a única forma é o operador `*`. Poderiam ter criado isto, mas pode ser confuso, acharam melhor não fazer, não importa onde use.

Comment: Muito bem esclarecido, então basicamente eu estava fazendo ponteiros sem saber kkk, este mundo do C é muito fascinante mesmo. Obrigado pela resposta vou procurar entender mais, neste tempo da pergunta até a resposta pelo que pesquisei o as é uma especie de 'cast' por isso não dava certo. Obrigado mais uma vez, tenha um ótimo final de ano.